# Not able to build angular2 project for prod

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to build my angular2 project for production but I am getting below error:-

```
C:\Official\UI\angular3>C:\Official\Software\node-v7.8.0-win-x64\ng build -prod -aot
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\build.js:14:56)
    at Class.run (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:162:26)
    at resolve (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:273:20)
    at Class.validateAndRun (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:251:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:157:24)
    at tryCatch (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Here is my Package.json:-

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17",
    "ng2-translate": "2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Can anybody help me here. I am not getting what is the issue. I even tried to delete node_module folder and reinstall it but all in vain.

I just created one empty new project with same package.json and it dont have my code at all but its still giving me same error. Not sure if its because of version mismatch in my package.json file.

Comment: Due you have any file name with config

Comment: No I don't have.. its a totally new project. I just checked node_modules\@angular\cli\tasksbuild.js file where its calling **CliConfig.fromProject()** but there is no such method in **@angular\cli\models\config\config.js**.. Not sure if it's bug or what?

Comment: I think you need to do tsconfig.json and systemjs configurations

Comment: My tsconfig is something like **'{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}'**

Comment: are you missing any files that `.angular-cli.json` is rely on? Have you checked that issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5879?

Comment: Yeah there is no .angular-cli.json but there is one angular-cli.json. is it same? if not, then from where will i get .angular-cli.json?

Comment: what is your cli version? It is equal or greater than `1.2.6` is it? Try to rename `angular-cli.json` in to `angular-cli.json`. Create the new `test project` and see if anything missing in yours by comparing the files.

Comment: My cli version is 1.2.6. I have already tried creating new project and renaming ' angular-cli.json ' to ' .angular-cli.json '.. but still getting same error..

Comment: Try to update to the latest stable one also try `1.3.0-rc` to see if it is giving you same error.

Comment: Still Same error...